# Segregate xml contents based on node value using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have an xml as given below. I want to extract all xml tags found between each #NEWPAGE# tag and save them separately to a sql sever database. Please suggest an approach.

Initially, I had a txt file containing the below detail but I thought of converting each line of the file into an xml tag line. Now, that I have an xml file. I'm not able to extract portion of the xml based on node value #NEWPAGE#.

---

XML content is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <Line>#HEADINGBEGIN#</Line>
       <Line></Line>
      <Line>Employee: 16062      Name: MERZLAK,BRIAN         Base: MSP  Eqpt: E70  Pos: CA</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>       Daily    On    Off          Daily  Daily                     Jr    Accum</Line>
      <Line>Date   Assign  Duty   Duty   TAFB  Block  Credit   Trip Guarantee   Man  Credit</Line>
      <Line>-----  ------ -----  -----  -----  -----  ------  ---------------  ----  ------</Line>
      <Line>#HEADINGEND#</Line>
      <Line>11/01  M2100A  0:01          0:00   4:35   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/02    "                   0:00   7:17   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/03    "           19:12  67:12   6:51  20:14    0:00            0:00   20:14 </Line>
      <Line>#GROUPNOBREAK#</Line>
      <Line>#GROUPBEGIN#</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>             Taxable TAFB    0:00                                              </Line>
      <Line>         Non-Taxable TAFB  178:00                                              </Line>
      <Line>               Total TAFB  178:00                                              </Line>
      <Line>#GROUPEND#</Line>
      <Line>#NEWPAGE#</Line>
      <Line>#HEADINGBEGIN#</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>Employee: 19814      Name: GRAYSON,MONIQUE       Base: LAX  Eqpt: E70  Pos: CA</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>       Daily    On    Off          Daily  Daily                     Jr    Accum</Line>
      <Line>Date   Assign  Duty   Duty   TAFB  Block  Credit   Trip Guarantee   Man  Credit</Line>
      <Line>-----  ------ -----  -----  -----  -----  ------  ---------------  ----  ------</Line>
      <Line>#HEADINGEND#</Line>
      <Line>11/01  OFF                   0:00   0:00   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/02  OFF                   0:00   0:00   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/03  L2488  13:30          0:00   7:10   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/04    "                   0:00   4:25   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>#GROUPNOBREAK#</Line>
      <Line>#GROUPBEGIN#</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>             Taxable TAFB    0:00                              Over Guar: 17:08</Line>
      <Line>         Non-Taxable TAFB  327:29                                              </Line>
      <Line>               Total TAFB  327:29                                              </Line>
      <Line>#GROUPEND#</Line>
      <Line>#NEWPAGE#</Line>
      <Line>#HEADINGBEGIN#</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>Employee: 20730      Name: ZAHN,GEOFFREY         Base: SEA  Eqpt: E70  Pos: CA</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>       Daily    On    Off          Daily  Daily                     Jr    Accum</Line>
      <Line>Date   Assign  Duty   Duty   TAFB  Block  Credit   Trip Guarantee   Man  Credit</Line>
      <Line>-----  ------ -----  -----  -----  -----  ------  ---------------  ----  ------</Line>
      <Line>#HEADINGEND#</Line>
      <Line>11/01  OFF                   0:00   0:00   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/02  OFF                   0:00   0:00   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>
      <Line>11/03  S2088  10:02          0:00   6:47   0:00    0:00            0:00    0:00 </Line>

      <Line>#GROUPNOBREAK#</Line>
      <Line>#GROUPBEGIN#</Line>
      <Line></Line>
      <Line>             Taxable TAFB    9:25                              Over Guar:  0:53</Line>
      <Line>         Non-Taxable TAFB  122:30                                              </Line>
      <Line>               Total TAFB  131:55                                              </Line>
    <Line>#GROUPEND#</Line>
    </root>
```

Comment: Great, Mr. Roy. But we don't write code for free. Show us your research efforts and to code you wrote so far.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you also have the text file. Then you can also use this simple approach -->

```
static void Main()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\yourTextFile.txt";
            string input = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string pattern = @"#HEADINGBEGIN#.*?#GROUPEND#";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();            
            foreach (var v in matches)
            {
                list.Add(v.ToString());
            }
            // Now save this list where ever you want.
        }
```

This gives all the employees data found between **#HEADINGBEGIN#** and **#GROUPEND#** separated by **#NEWPAGE#**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Linq` to `Xml` and achieve this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var result = doc.Descendants("Line")                      // Get all descendants of Line
        .SkipWhile(x=> (string)x.Value == "#NEWPAGE#")    // Skip Lines till we found tag.
        .TakeWhile(x=>(string)x.Value != "#NEWPAGE#")     // Take lines until we found other tag.
        .ToList();

// Write to file
File.WriteAllLines(newfile,result.Select(x=>x.ToString()); // TODO : Provide filename
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L6YFme)

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach looks quite weak... I'm sure there was a much better concept to do this. But to answer your question: You can number your lines, find the `#NEWPAGE#` tags and use them to split your result set:

**Attention: This uses `LEAD`, available since SQL Server 2012**

**UPDATE** I would pass the XML to a Stored Procedure as parameter *as is* and do the parsing there...

```
DECLARE @xml XML='Your XML here';
WITH AllLines AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNr
          ,Line.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Content
    FROM @xml.nodes('root/Line') AS One(Line)
)
,NewPages AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS NewpageStart --the very first line has no #NEWPAGE#...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNr FROM AllLines WHERE Content='#NEWPAGE#'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 999999 --Needs a final mark too...
)
,PageBorders AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PageNr
          ,NewpageStart+1 AS NewPageStart
          ,LEAD(NewPageStart) OVER(ORDER BY NewPageStart)-1  AS NewPageEnd
    FROM NewPages
)
SELECT PageNr
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PageNr ORDER BY RowNr) AS PageRowNr
      ,AllLines.*
FROM PageBorders
INNER JOIN AllLines ON AllLines.RowNr BETWEEN PageBorders.NewPageStart AND PageBorders.NewPageEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication102
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            FIND_HEADINGBEGIN,
            HEADINGBEGIN,
            EMPLOYEE,
            FIND_GROUPBEGIN,
            GROUP
        }
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = ParseXml(FILENAME);
        }
        static List<Employee> ParseXml(string filename)
        {
            string employeePattern = @"Employee:\s*(?'employee'\d*)\s+Name:\s*(?'name'[^\s]*)\s*Base:\s+(?'base'[^\s]*)\s*Eqpt:\s+(?'eqpt'[^\s]*)\s+Pos:\s+(?'pos'[^\s]*)";
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            Employee newEmployee = null;
            List<int> assmentColumnWidths = new List<int>() {7, 7, 14, 7, 7, 8, 16, 8, 8};
            int lineNo = 0;
            State state = State.FIND_HEADINGBEGIN;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            foreach (XElement xLine in doc.Descendants("Line"))
            {
                string line = ((string)xLine).Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_HEADINGBEGIN:
                            if (line.StartsWith("#HEADINGBEGIN#"))
                            {
                                state = State.HEADINGBEGIN;
                                lineNo = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.HEADINGBEGIN:
                            if (line.StartsWith("#HEADINGEND#"))
                            {
                                state = State.EMPLOYEE;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (lineNo++ == 0)
                                {
                                    newEmployee = new Employee();
                                    employees.Add(newEmployee);
                                    Match expr = Regex.Match(line, employeePattern);
                                    newEmployee.id = expr.Groups["employee"].Value;
                                    newEmployee.name = expr.Groups["name"].Value;
                                    newEmployee._base = expr.Groups["base"].Value;
                                    newEmployee.eqpt = expr.Groups["eqpt"].Value;
                                    newEmployee.pos = expr.Groups["pos"].Value;
                                    newEmployee.eqpt = expr.Groups["eqpt"].Value;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.EMPLOYEE:
                            if (line.StartsWith("#GROUPNOBREAK#"))
                            {
                                state = State.FIND_GROUPBEGIN;
                                lineNo = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                List<string> assignmentData = GetFixedWidth(line, assmentColumnWidths);
                                Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
                                if (newEmployee.assignments == null) newEmployee.assignments = new List<Assignment>();
                                newEmployee.assignments.Add(assignment);
                                assignment.date = assignmentData[0];
                                assignment.name = (assignmentData[1] == "\"") ? newEmployee.assignments[newEmployee.assignments.Count - 2].name : assignmentData[1];
                                assignment.onDuty = assignmentData[2];
                                assignment.offDuty = assignmentData[3];
                                assignment.tafb = assignmentData[4];
                                assignment.dailyBlock = assignmentData[5];
                                assignment.dailyCredit = assignmentData[6];
                                assignment.tripGuarantee = assignmentData[7];
                                assignment.jrMan = assignmentData[8];

                            }
                            break;
                        case State.FIND_GROUPBEGIN:
                            if (line.StartsWith("#GROUPBEGIN#"))
                            {
                                state = State.GROUP;
                                Total total = new Total();
                                newEmployee.total = new Total();
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.GROUP:
                            if (line.StartsWith("#GROUPEND#"))
                            {
                                state = State.FIND_HEADINGBEGIN;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                switch (++lineNo)
                                {
                                    case 1 :
                                        newEmployee.total.taxable = splitLine[2];
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        newEmployee.total.nonTaxable = splitLine[2];
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        newEmployee.total.total = splitLine[2];
                                        break;
                                }

                            }
                            break;

                    }

                }
            }
            return employees;
        }
        static List<string> GetFixedWidth(string input, List<int> columns)
        {
            int index = 0;
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            for (int startPos = 0; (startPos < input.Length) && (index < columns.Count); startPos += columns[index])
            {
                if (startPos + columns[index] <= input.Length)
                {
                    output.Add(input.Substring(startPos, columns[index++]).Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(input.Substring(startPos).Trim());
                }

            }
            return output;
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string _base { get; set; }
        public string eqpt { get; set; }
        public string pos { get; set; }
        public List<Assignment> assignments { get; set; }
        public Total total { get; set; }

    }
    public class Assignment
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string onDuty { get; set; }
        public string offDuty { get; set; }
        public string tafb { get; set; }
        public string dailyBlock { get; set; }
        public string dailyCredit { get; set; }
        public string tripGuarantee { get; set; }
        public string jrMan { get; set; }
    }
    public class Total
    {
        public string taxable { get; set; }
        public string nonTaxable { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }
    }
}
```